# Pronunciation rules for "CH" and "arch-"

Tags: pronunciation, etymology, suffixes, prefixes

Yesterday I was watching Pokémon where I encountered this word "archenemy". It is definitely not the first time I am hearing it, though it is the first time I am putting thought into it.

When I googled the word **arch** I found four different meanings and usages. Two of them are just the raw words arch, while one uses it as a prefix (arch-) and another one as suffix (-arch).

However, I have always heard **archenemy** pronounced as *arch-enemy* with the /t͡ʃ/ ⟨ch⟩ pronunciation very evident. On the other hand, **monarch** is pronounced as *mon-arc* with the ⟨ch⟩ replaced with /k/. But the Google pronunciation for arch<sup>**1**</sup> ([Google Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+arch)) which is the suffix form, is pronounced as 'arch' with a /t͡ʃ/ ⟨ch⟩ pronunciation. Is that a mistake?

Also, I would like to know the etymology of these words and how come they are pronounced different if they have the same Greek origin word ***arkhos*** (I did not make it, Google said that)?

<sup>**1**</sup> combining form, **suffix: -arch**
(forming nouns) denoting a ruler or leader. Example: "monarch"

Comment: Oh that is to indicate that it was the fourth meaning there on Google. Wait let me fix it,

Comment: The fourth pronunciation on Google has a k, not ch. Is it right?

Comment: Not when you hear it. I replaced the word 'given' with 'pronounced' so that people won't get confused.

Comment: Ah.... yes, that's a mistake. They've given the transcription with a /k/ and pronounce it with a <ch>. That's incorrect.

Comment: Strangely, the 'ch' is pronounced differently in the prefix of [**archbishop**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/archbishop) (soft) and [**archangel**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/archangel) (hard). Also the suffix is different in [**starch**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/starch) (soft) and [**matriarch**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/matriarch) (hard).

Comment: I tend to say "arc" instead of "arch" for most words with it in, so  I would not pronounce them different... but I suspect I'm just incorrectly pronouncing things, and there are indeed silly differences as described above due to language changing over time and corrupting words from the same root into different sounds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no consistent rules for the pronunciation of the digraph ⟨ch⟩; it can be pronounced either /k/ or /t͡ʃ/, depending on the origin of the word.
There are some general guidelines, but they too have exceptions.

Adam Brown in his *[Understanding and Teaching English Spelling](https://books.google.com/books/about/Understanding_and_Teaching_English_Spell.html?id=lEBvDwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)* suggests that the digraph ⟨ch⟩ has three main pronunciations [modified]:

- /tʃ/ in Anglo-Saxon words, e.g. *church, chicken, teach, speech, much, beach, Chelsea*
- /ʃ/ in words of French origin, e.g. *chef, machine, champagne, niche, chalet, charade, panache*
- /k/ in words of Greek origin, e.g. *chemist, chaos, Christopher, ache, monarch*

#### ⟨ch⟩+Consonant in the beginning

When the digraph ⟨ch⟩ precedes a consonant in a single word, it's almost always pronounced /k/ and not /t͡ʃ/, probably because [English Phonotactics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics#English_phonotactics) doesn't allow [affricates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affricate) (/t͡ʃ/ and /d͡ʒ/) in complex [onsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable#Onset) i.e. /t͡ʃ/ and /d͡ʒ/ cannot make an onset cluster. Therefore the ⟨ch⟩ in words like *chlorine, chrome, Christ* etc., is pronounced /k/.
Words starting *chr-* and *chl-* are mostly of Greek origin and are pronounced with /k/.

#### ⟨ch⟩ in Greek-derived words

The ⟨ch⟩ is usually pronounced /k/ in words that are [derived from Greek](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/5028/365490) like *monarch*, *amphibrach, anarchy, archaic, anchor* etc.

The prefix *arch-* is [derived from Greek](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=arch-) and it means *important* or *chief*. It has a few forms in English (*arch-*, *archi-* and *arche-*), all borrowed from Greek (*arkh-, arkhi-, arkhe-*) which is confusing.

The only thing that comes to mind is that it's pronounced with a /k/ in simple words like *architect, archaic, archive* etc., and pronounced /t͡ʃ/ in compound words such as *archenemy, archbishop, archduke* etc., though it has many, many exceptions like *archangel*.

#### ⟨arch-⟩ in compound words

- Words that were compounded with ⟨arch-⟩ in Greek are also pronounced with a /k/ such as *archangel* (from Greek arkhangelos; compound of *arkhi-* and *angelos*).
- Compound words in which the prefix *arch-* is prepended to an English word, the ⟨ch⟩ is pronounced /t͡ʃ/ such as *archenemy* ([from Greek *arch-* and English *enemy*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archenemy#Etymology)).

#### ⟨arch-⟩ in the beginning of Greek words

When ⟨arch-⟩ begins a Greek word and is followed by a vowel it's almost always pronounced with a /k/ as in *archangel, archipelago, architect, archive, archaism* etc.

#### ⟨arch-⟩ in the beginning of English words

When the ⟨arch-⟩ is prepended to an English word and it begins with a consonant, it's almost always pronounced with a /t͡ʃ/. Examples include *archduke, archdeakon, archbishop*.

There may be exceptions and irregularities, however.

---

## Quotes from other sources

According to the [*Dictionary of the British English Spelling System* by Greg Brooks](https://books.google.com/books?id=sgh2CAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s), the digraph ⟨ch⟩ is also pronounced /k/ in words that begin with ⟨arch-⟩ when followed by a vowel letter as in *archaic, archive, architect, archetype* etc. However, there are only two common exceptions; ***arch-enemy*** and ***archer***.

According to [*A Survey of English Spelling*](https://books.google.com/books?id=LKu_sHE8WBYC&vq=arch&source=gbs_navlinks_s) by Edward Carney, ⟨arch-⟩ is pronounced /k/ before *i* and *y*, though he doesn't explain it further and leaves us with many questions.

According to [*The History of English Spelling* by Upward and Davidson](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_History_of_English_Spelling.html?id=fNfebt79zdwC), the English value of ⟨ch⟩ as /t͡ʃ/ originated in [Old French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_French) and was integrated into English after the [Norman Conquest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_conquest_of_England). They've given some other examples like *bachelor, brooch, butcher, chair, chamber, chance, exchequer, franchise, merchant, treachery.*

The authors further go on to say that the ⟨ch⟩ is pronounced /ʃ/ in more recent borrowings like *brochure, chalet, champagne, chateau, chef, chic, cliché, moustache,nonchalant, etc.*

Here's a more detailed explanation of the ⟨ch⟩ in [*The History of English Spelling*](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_History_of_English_Spelling.html?id=fNfebt79zdwC):

> [image: CH]

And about *arch-*:

> [image: arch-]

Also from [*English Words: History and Structure* by Stockwell and Minkova](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521709172):

> [image: Digraph ch]

<sup>/t͡ʃ/ is the sound in ***ch**ip*

/d͡ʒ/ as in ***j**am*

/ʃ/ as in ***sh**ip*

/k/ as in ***k**ing*</sup>

---

#### References:

- [A Critical Pronouncing Dictionary (John Walker)](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Critical_Pronouncing_Dictionary_and_Ex.html?id=_faiUKL5zRsC&redir_esc=y)
- [Dictionary of the British English Spelling System by Greg Brooks](https://books.google.com/books?id=sgh2CAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s)
- [The History of English Spelling by Upward and Davidson](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_History_of_English_Spelling.html?id=fNfebt79zdwC)
- [A Survey of English Spelling by Edward Carney](https://books.google.com/books?id=LKu_sHE8WBYC&vq=arch&source=gbs_navlinks_s)
- [English Words: History and Structure by Stockwell and Minkova](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521709172)
- [The History of English Spelling](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_History_of_English_Spelling.html?id=fNfebt79zdwC)

Comment: Sorry for accepting your answer so late. I had intended to wait for a whole day before accepting yours as an official answer, but looks like I forgot later that your answer was waiting to be accepted. And I hardly think someone would be able to provide a more concrete version than this. But of course, anyone is welcome to post an answer. Thank you once again. There are parts and bits I didn't understand in your answer (because I am new to phonetics), but don't you worry, I am studying on it.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh: No worries. Ask any questions you have